# MySQL Change Tracking

Tags: mysql

SQL Server 2008 had a new feature called "SQL Server 2008 Change Tracking".

Is there a MySQL equivalent?

I'm after any kind of change tracking (to keep a separate MS SQL Server in sync) that does not need schema changes (triggers, extra column, etc).

Comment: Hehehe SQL 2008 isn't "New" anymore. ;)  Perhaps you could edit your question to explain the features of SQL's Change Tracking that's you'd like to find in MySQL?  Which features have you already found to exist in your MySQL version?  Which one have you not (yet) found?  It'll help the people who know MySQL but not MS SQL be able to provide you and answer without going and studying.

Comment: Is my question really worthy of a -1?  It was new to SQL Server 2008.  That is what I meant.

Comment: It was worth a -1 (IMO) because you hadn't bothered to show any research effort (Have you actually installed MySQL and checked for it?  Have you looked through the MySQL documentation for similar features?), nor did you explain what it is you are actually looking for.   You fixed that (by making it less vague) so I'll take my -1 back. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer to me would be MySQL replication logs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

These logs track all changes made to the database necessary to replicate it onto another server, although simply storing them locally forever is also an option.